# append dictionary values python from if condition one liner

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an empty dictionary `hashtags_dict` where i would like to fill up with multiple values for each key when it satisfies a condition. `haystack_types`contains the keys

```
for (some_loop):
  eggs = get_new_egg()
  if (needle):
    for category in haystack_types: 
      try:
        hashtags_dict[category].append(eggs if needle in haystack_types[category])
      except KeyError:
        hashtags_dict[category] = [eggs if needle in haystack_types[category]]
```

There is a syntax error with in the `try` block.
I would like to do it in a one-liner.

Comment: I think it is better to use `in` rather than `try...except`

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2: the `try.. except` is because, when new values are added, it cannot be appended. so it throws a key error..

Comment: @IronFist: its `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.. what would you expect..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a conditional expression without an `else` clause. Expressions *must* produce something, and yours doesn't when `if needle in haystack_types[category]` is false.

Either produce `None` or use a proper `if` statement:

```
if needle in haystack_types[category]:
    hashtags_dict[category].append(eggs)
```

You could use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) here to handle the case where `hashtags_dict` doesn't yet have that list:

```
for category in haystack_types: 
    if needle in haystack_types[category]:
        hashtags_dict.setdefault(category, []).append(eggs)
```

`dict.setdefault()` uses the second argument as a default value if the key (the first argument) is missing, so the above will set the key to an empty list the first time you try to access a given key.

You could make the `if` statement a little more concise by using `dict.items()` to access the `haystack_types` values in the loop:

```
for category, types in haystack_types.items(): 
    if needle in types:
        hashtags_dict.setdefault(category, []).append(eggs)
```

Comment: so does `setdefault(category,[]).append()` appends new values for the key, as wel as assigns new values.. right ?

Comment: @blueBeetle: `dict.setdefault()` will either return the value for the given key, or if the key is missing, use the second argument to set that key to a default first, then return the value.